# Floating div after certain % of website scrolling

Tags: html, floating

I really don't know where to start to search. And to be honest I did not even know how to search for, because I don't know how it calls. (maybe headsup? but all I get is car tuning stuff)

What am I looking for its in the attached image. 
When a user scrolls a certain percentage of the website, it appears a message. When "mouse over" the message, it expands. I would like to do something like the images attached.

Do anyone know where i can search for that? And for what?

Hope anyone can help me.

Greetings
Constantin

[at the bottom right is the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJyck.jpg)

[mouse over, expands the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6dCK.jpg)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/d010s4rg/ maybe this will help you .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is a too broad for a direct answer, so it most likely will need to be closed. However the idea you are describing can be achieved using CSS animations and JavaScript. Create a JS event listener for the `onscroll` event, and trigger CSS animations when it crosses a threshold. To make the message "grow", a simple CSS `hover` state should work.

Answer (score 2):

Or yo can use only css

```css
   

#div1{
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#div1:hover{
height:300px;

    -moz-transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#div1 {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
}
#div1:hover {
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</div>
```

Modifying @Mostafa's code a bit, you can also have a smooth transition back.

Also, the [`transition` property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) does not need [prefixes](http://shouldiprefix.com/#transitions) in recent versions of all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

cool, thank you so much guys....

*edit: but what's the code to make it appear at the bottom right corner of the page and to be sticky? - i mean when I scroll the page it remains at the bottom right corner...